# Nicely formatted 'where' statement for Maths

Tags: amsmath

Is there any way to accomplish this nicely in latex:

[image]

See how there is a 'where' clause afterwards that specifies what all of the variables represent? Is there a nice way of typesetting that inside the mathematics block or would you just write:

```
\emph{where}
\begin{itemize}
    \item blah blah blah
    ...
\end{itemize}
```

I'm really looking for a special latex math method of doing what you see in the image above.

Comment: Do you also want the box around the formula?

Comment: I usually do it outside the math environment, with a `\noindent` before.

Comment: I do it outside the math block too, usually. These definitions belong to the text, not to the equation, in my opinion. Also, there is no need for `\noindent` if you don't leave any blank line between the equation and the "where" statement, actually. Just type it as you would type the end of a sentence containing an equation.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino There is no need for the box typesetting. I am just concerned with the 'where' section that defines what the variables mean. It seems so far like everybody just writes it straight into the text but I'll leave this question open to see if somebody does this in a clever or different way. Thanks for the comments so far.

Comment: I would do it as T.Verron does. I was hoping that we could use the the new `norndcorners` feature of @ClaudioFiandrino's [`hf-tikz`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/hf-tikz/) package here. `:-)`

Comment: @RobertMassaioli If the question I linked was what you were looking for, it's better to close this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your own `where` environment that automates this process:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{where}{\noindent{}where\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{where}
  \item Statement 1
  \item Statement 2
  \item Statement 3
\end{where}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)